# R: "Error in m[, 1L] : incorrect number of dimensions" when installing a package

Tags: r

When trying to install a package in R I get the following odd error and R does not load and return the CRAN selection menu. What causes this?

```
> install.packages("rJava")
Warning in install.packages("rJava") :
  argument 'lib' is missing: using '/home/jal/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.11'
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Loading Tcl/Tk interface ... done
Error in m[, 1L] : incorrect number of dimensions
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the error was caused by networking issues. My wifi was connected but the access point required loading a web form and entering a user name and password. I had been logged in but been dropped and had to re-authenticate. Once I logged back in it worked fine.

I think the error message could be a bit more insightful.

Comment: It's useful to state your R version number (?) and platform (Linux 64b). If it has not already been fixed in a recent version, [send them a bug report](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#R-Bugs)...

Comment: Thanks @smci. The platform was 64 bit Linux and the R version was 2.11. That's implicit in the lib assumption that R makes, however, I agree that it's good to be explicit when asking questions.

Comment: Agreed. My point was to prove to people that you had checked it was not a documented known issue, or worse still, an already solved issue :) R surprises me in that every time I personally have been on the point of posting an SO question about an error message, and done a preliminary check, it was very rare that the issue was *completely* unknown (although most of the time, poorly or obscurely documented or not widely known). Having said that, even bad error messages on known issues can constitute 'documentation bugs'...